# Gravityforms horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css, gravityforms

Gravityforms are an mess to try to align horizontal.

Used their css readymade gf_inline to break them out of the column but have no clue on how to align them?

[lines are all over the place?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQqhY.gif)

Comment: I'll include this here as a comment; my original answer was deleted by a powerful wizard: https://gravitywiz.com/build-horizontal-forms-gravity-forms/

Comment: Yeah i've used that.. thanks! But it's the weird styling thats a miss. When I put text in a html element it is forced top aligned. it's really hard to align it horizontal.